# Python Assigning a Variable to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, parameters

My input dataframe;

```
A      B      Active
2      3      1
3      4      0
4      5      1
5      3      0
2      3      1
```

I want to assign a variable/ parameter from outside. 
If the outside variable is 55, "A" columns values will be "0 (zero)" according to "Active" column.

```
Variable = 55

A      B      Active
2      3      1
0      4      0
4      5      1
0      3      0
2      3      1
```

If the variable is 555, A columns values will be remain same. So, the "Active" column will be ignored and not activated.

```
Variable = 555

A      B      Active
2      3      1
3      4      0
4      5      1
5      3      0
2      3      1
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: df['A'] = df['A'].where(df['Active'].ne(0), 0)

Comment: @splash58, that' s not meet my demand exactly, i edited the question.